AutoHotKey V2: Issuing HTTP request on PBT_APMSUSPEND event sometimes fails. Windows doesn't give enough time to do anything before sleeping
I'm trying to automate turning off my miniDSP Flex when I put my computer into sleep mode (or hibernate), if miniDSP is currently turned on.
The script below sends an HTTP request to a learning remote via its API when I put my computer into sleep mode (if miniDSP is turned on). The remote then toggles power of my miniDSP by sending a learned IR signal.
I've tried listening to the PBT_APMSUSPEND event. Unfortunately, this doesn't always work: Windows doesn't give the script enough time to do anything useful. The HTTP request for turning off my miniDSP sometimes doesn't complete before the computer goes into sleep mode. When I resume the computer, the request get sent, causing the miniDSP to turn off after resuming.
I've already tried moving the miniDSP power state query outside of the PBT_APMSUSPEND handler function, because testing if the miniDSP is turned on by running minidsp-rs takes too long. Even with that, the HTTP request sometimes doesn't complete before sleeping.
Are there any workarounds? Or is there another way to automate turning off the miniDSP?
Another solution that could work might be setting up a new hotkey that turns off miniDSP and then puts the system to sleep. I should remember to put the computer into sleep mode only by using that hotkey.
minidsp-rs does not seem to have a command for turning off the miniDSP, unfortunately.
MiniDSPExe := "C:\miniDSP\minidsp.exe"
MiniDSPTurnedOn := false
RemoURL := "http://192.168.50.73/messages"
RemoRequestBody := FileRead("toggle_power.json")

LogFile := "C:\miniDSPAutoToggler\MiniDSPAutoToggler.log"

WHR := ComObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

WM_POWERBROADCAST := 0x218
PBT_APMSUSPEND := 4

; file log
flog(params*){
    ts := FormatTime(, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.") substr(A_TickCount,-3)

    for ,param in params
      message .= param . " "
    FileAppend ts " " message "`n", LogFile
}

flog("Started miniDSPAutoToggler.ahk")

_WM_POWERBROADCAST(wParam, lParam, msg, hwnd) {
    Critical(1000)
    flog "wParam " wParam
    if (wParam = PBT_APMSUSPEND) {
        flog "The system is entering a suspended state"
        ToggleMiniDSP(false)
    }
}

LogMiniDSPState() {
    flog "miniDSP turned on: " MiniDSPTurnedOn
}

RefreshMiniDSPState() {
    global MiniDSPTurnedOn
    exitCode := RunWait(MiniDSPExe, , "Hide")
    MiniDSPTurnedOn := exitCode == 0
    LogMiniDSPState()
}

ToggleMiniDSP(turnOn) {
    global MiniDSPTurnedOn
    if (MiniDSPTurnedOn != turnOn) {
        WHR.Open("POST", remoURL, false)
        WHR.SetRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "local")
        WHR.Send(remoRequestBody)
        status := WHR.Status
        if (status = 200) {
            flog "Successfully sent a HTTP request to Nature Remo"
        } else {
            flog "HTTP request to remo failed with status code " status
        }
    } else {
        flog "miniDSP is already in a desired power state"
    }

    MiniDSPTurnedOn := turnOn
    LogMiniDSPState()

    return true
}

RefreshMiniDSPState()
SetTimer(RefreshMiniDSPState, 60000)

OnMessage(WM_POWERBROADCAST, _WM_POWERBROADCAST)

